Show comments (activities) from sharepoint list in a gallery (power apps)
I use sharepoint lists to tasks management, when I need to write some observation I use this "comment" text field that stores activity logs.
I'm bringing this list to this screen app in power plataform with power apps but I'm not reaching how to show this activities in a gallery or something else.
In gallery it's not listed in the field lists that can be showed.
I'm learning.
I can't set Title = ThisItem.Activity or something like this, there is not any field that shows the activity in this way, if there's another way, let me know.
